# How to send SMS (Text Message) From iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to send SMS(Text) from iPad. I have search many Apple Blogs where people are saying that iPad does not support Calling and Text sending service but during my search i come across the Appliction which is sending the Text messages from iPad here is the Link of that Application [http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textie-messaging/id353912946?mt=8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages with the iPad over the internet (like iMessages does in the new iOS, Facebook Messages, Google+ and WhatsApp are other examples). But you can't send messages over the GSM/CDMA network using the iPad since the hardware of an iPad doesn't support this kind of data protocol.

Comment: Is all the Apps which are sending and receiving Text messages from iPad using internet ? or there is any API or Farm work which can do this for iPad ? if they are sending from internet than can u please guide me which internet service is suitable for this

Comment: Since internet is the only datasource an iPad has, it's the only way.